# How many possible combinations/permutations for 5 letters and 5 numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have been given a scenario that includes a generated code that contains 5 alphabetic characters (A-Z) and 5 numbers (0-9). When concatenated, the code looks something like:

```
ABCDE12345
```

I have tried splitting them in two and calculating the possible combinations for the letters and numbers separately but I am unsure what to use for ***n*** and ***r***.

Comment: To be clear, you are asking how many strings of length ten exist where the first five characters are uppercase letters and the last five characters are numerals where repitition is allowed?  Apply multiplication principle.  How many choices for the first character?  For the second?  For the third? ... For the tenth?  Multiply the number of options available for each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem depends on whether or not you can repeat letters. If you can repeat letters there are $26$ choices for each letter and $10$ choices for each digit. In such a case there are
$
26^5\times 10 ^5
$
ways.

If you can't repeat letters then we have to arrange $5$ letters from $26$ possible letters and arrange $5$ numbers from $10$ numbers (the two choices are independent). In this case there are
$
P(26,5)\times P(10, 5)
$
ways.